How to get handle to dragged item -- HTML drag and drop API
I'm using the HTML drag and drop API. When dragging an element, I want to get separate handles to the draggable element (the original element) and to the dragged element (the moveable copy of the original element).
I can't figure out how to manipulate one without changing the other. The example below shows how both elements turn red when the drag begins


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
.red {
  background: red;
  border: 5px solid #aaaaaa;
}
#drag1 {
    height: 69px;
    width: 336px;
    border: 5px solid #aaaaaa;
}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.target.classList.add('red');
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">drop here</div>
<br>
<div id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">drag me</div>

</body>
</html>



